# Cast a generic param to a specific type

Tags: generics, rust, casting

If I have two structs:

```
struct A {...}
struct B {...}
```

and a generic function `fn f<T>(param: T)` that I call with passing either a reference to `A` or `B`, is there a way in that function to have something like this (pseudo code):

```
if param is A {
    // do something with "param as A", like this:
    let a: A = (A) param;
    // ...
}
```

In languages like Java, C#, etc. I would simply check if an object is an instance of `A` and if so, cast it to `A` as in the example above. How can I do something like that in Rust? I know I could put some type-specific logic in a trait, but I'm specifically asking for a simpler, more direct way.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html

Comment: Can you describe your specific use case? There are several approaches for type-specific behaviour, and which one to pick depends on your requirements and preferences.

Answer (score 5):

You can do exactly what you are asking for using trait objects of the `Any` trait, e.g.

```
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;

fn foo(param: &dyn Any) {
    if let Some(a) = param.downcast_ref::<A>() {
        dbg!(a);
    }
    if let Some(b) = param.downcast_ref::<B>() {
        dbg!(b);
    }
}
```

However, for common use cases there are more idiomatic, ergonomic and efficient solutions. You mentioned implementing a common trait on `A` and `B` in your question, which is one approach. Another approach is defining an enum with variants for all types you want to support:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

fn bar(param: MyEnum) {
    match param {
        MyEnum::A(a) => { dbg!(a); },
        MyEnum::B(b) => { dbg!(b); },
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning a few things here: (1) using `&dyn Any` will adversely affect performance, due to extra indirection; (2) Java and C# use boxed types by default, which is why they are able to do this without extra effort; (3) depending on type inspection at runtime makes your abstractions leaky and is usually a sign that your abstractions were poorly designed in the first place. You can't compare Rust with Java or C# because they are completely different beasts.