# Cast a struct with a generic type parameter to a specific type

Tags: generics, rust, casting

*Note: Earlier today I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705142/cast-a-generic-param-to-a-specific-type), but this one has a significant difference, so I am posting it as a separate question.*

If I have two (or more) structs:

```
struct A {...}
struct B {...}
```

and a generic function `fn f<T>(param: Vec<T>)` that I call with passing a vector of `A` or `B` (or some other type for that matter), is there a way in that function to have something like this (pseudo code):

```
if param is Vec<A> {
    // do something with "param as Vec<A>", like this:
    let a: Vec<A> = (Vec<A>) param;
    // ...
}
```

Typically in OOP languages I could basically check the type of the vector parameter or one of its elements (given the vector is not empty) and cast the parameter.

In Rust, is there a **simple** and **direct** way to achieve that, w/o sacrificing performance and w/o the need to change the function signature or write any code outside the function (so no enum wrappers, traits, dyn/runtime "magic", etc.).

Comment: did you try using match? also it doesn't feel really different, it seems you are not satisfied with the answer on the other question. You could have edited the other question so as to specify why the proposed solution is inadequate and/or added a bounty on the question.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier
I don't understand how match could help here? I decided to post a separate question, because here I'm asking for something like `Vec<T>` and the other question is more generic, for `T`.

Comment: What would `param` originally be in that context? That in one place it is called with a vector of `A` and in another one it is called with a vector of `B` means one of two things: 1) the two types share a common behavior which can be exposed into a common trait; or 2) they should be separate functions.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to give a proper answer. Could you give more context about what you're trying to do? The current code example isn't enough to deduce what your actual needs are. Need to answer @ᕮ_ᑎᕮT4 's questions

Comment: Guys, I really don't know how to explain it better. If I try to come up with a (reasonably) short example, it would look artificial and I would probably be advised that such a feature is not needed. I had a situation, in a rather large code base, where I wanted to do just that: add some code that works on `Vec<A>` **if** `T` is `A` and I realized I don't know **how** to do such a "cast" in Rust. The only ideas that came to mind were way too complicated and I really didn't want to change the signature of the function and affect all the callers.

Comment: Firstly, I presume that "simple" and "direct" here refer to the ergonomics, concision and/or clarity of the source code.  However these are somewhat subjective measures, and it's very hard for us to judge what you might consider to be simple and/or direct.

Comment: Secondly, because Rust puts so much focus on zero-cost abstractions, often one can (and *should*) just create abstractions that more faithfully model the problem—and no performance will be sacrificed.  Indeed, "performance" is *usually* something one ought to have in the back of one's mind but not strive to attain at the cost of clear, understandable and maintainable code: only if a performance bottleneck is identified with careful profiling should one start optimising to eliminate it.

Comment: Thirdly, one of the tenets of eXtreme Programming is *refactor mercilessly*, and for good reason.  Placing restrictions such as "*w/o the need to change the function signature or write any code outside the function*" violates this principle.  And since Rust's type system enables *fearless refactoring*, this restriction really makes no sense at all.

Comment: I think you're getting pushback because traits and enums are the intended mechanisms for polymorphism. Rust is *not* an OOP language. The way to do those cast's in other languages are via a mechanism similar to the `Any` trait. However, most would shy away from that because its not a well-composed way to provide polymorphism.

Comment: @kmdreko I totally agree with you. My question wasn't about searching for a way to implement polymorphism in Rust though. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for, so I accepted it. Thanks!

Comment: But your previous comment overlooked that, while adding a `where T: Trait` constraint to the function would indeed change its signature, it doesn’t require any changes to callers.  `A` and `B` would of course need to implement `Trait` but that’s pretty simple.  `Trait` could then perform whatever behaviour is required here, or perhaps simply provide an associated boolean constant if that’s all you require (which would then be accessed within your function eg `if T::IS_A { … }`).

Comment: @at54321 Being at the receiving end of such criticism myself, I have a lot of sympathy for your position. But please keep in mind that your question, as written, is _extremely_ restrictive. For example, you expressly forbid _dyn/runtime "magic"_, and then accept the answer that employs exactly such magic.

Comment: @user4815162342 You are right, by bad. Thanks for pointing that out. The reason I excluded "dyn/runtime magic" was I thought that would require changing the parameter signature and probably using some sort of a boxing at the vector elements level (something like `Vec<Box<T>>`). As it turns out though, that's not necessary and in the accepted answer's example, the compiler actually *knows* that `_param_a` **is** `Vec<A>` - so at that point there should be zero overhead in using `_param_a`.

Comment: @at54321 Good point about zero overhead, it'd be interesting to check the generated assembly. Note that the accepted answer did change the signature - `f` now requires `T: 'static`, which means that you can't call it with e.g. a vector of references (to non-static data). It's still _useful_ (all owned types satisfy the new bound, so you didn't have to change your callers), but it definitely changed its scope. I've now added an answer that addresses the question in the way you meant to (I think), with the downside that it requires a nightly feature that might take years to get into stable Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the `Any` approach as shown in the linked question if you are able to constrain `T: 'static`

```
use std::any::Any;

struct A {}
struct B {}

fn f<T: 'static>(param: Vec<T>) {
    if let Some(_param_a) = (&param as &dyn Any).downcast_ref::<Vec<A>>() {
        println!("I am a Vec<A>");
    }
    else {
        println!("I am something else");
    }
}

fn main() {
    f(Vec::<A>::new());
    f(Vec::<B>::new());
}
```

This does not have any runtime cost.

Comment: That looks great and is pretty much what I was asking for! Thanks, kmdreko!

Comment: [An example](https://godbolt.org/z/jPj378EqE) showing that there's no run-time cost.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** the answer suggests that specialization is on the verge of landing in stable Rust. Although it looked like that at the time, that doesn't appear to be the case as of 2024. The specialization as available on nightly (including the minimal implementation) was found to be unsound and will not be stabilized in that form.

---

What you're looking for is not yet *quite* available in current Rust, but will become available once the specialization feature lands. Using specialization, and testable on current nightly, your function would look like this:

```
#![feature(min_specialization)]

struct A {}
struct B {}

fn f<T>(param: Vec<T>) {
    trait Detect {
        fn detect(&self);
    }
    impl<T> Detect for Vec<T> {
        default fn detect(&self) {
            println!("I am something else");
        }
    }
    impl Detect for Vec<A> {
        fn detect(&self) {
            println!("I am a Vec<A>");
        }
    }
    param.detect();
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    f(Vec::<A>::new());
    f(Vec::<B>::new());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80aa555168e839a92e6763eb1e9dca69)

It can be even made generic by providing a "cast"-like trait:

```
trait Cast<To> {
    fn with_cast(&self, fun: impl FnOnce(Option<&To>));
}

impl<T, To> Cast<To> for T {
    default fn with_cast(&self, fun: impl FnOnce(Option<&To>)) {
        fun(None)
    }
}
```

Using `Cast`, the `f` function would look like this:

```
fn f<T>(param: Vec<T>) {
    impl Cast<Vec<A>> for Vec<A> {
        fn with_cast(&self, fun: impl FnOnce(Option<&Self>)) {
            fun(Some(self));
        }
    }
    param.with_cast(|val: Option<&Vec<A>>| {
        if let Some(_param_a) = val {
            // here I can access fields of param_a
            println!("I'm a Vec<A>");
        } else {
            println!("I'm something else");
        }
    });
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f19a192adb2f1bec79eed01da6500b53)

Comment: +1. That would be more verbose than the accepted answer, but it does have the (potential) benefit of not having to change `f<T>` to `f<T: 'static>`. I find both answers useful. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Strange... I'm pretty sure I did upvote your answer (that's why I wrote "+1"), but I might have been wrong (either I was or there was a bug). Anyway, now I upvoted. :)

Comment: @at54321 While at it, I added a slightly more general variant of the code. Specialization is a bit weird when you use it raw, but it allows building really nice abstractions.

Comment: +1 Very useful and works with crate feature `#![feature(min_specialization)]`. Provides a nice way of specifying generic methods in Traits and specializing their implementation